# Organizing fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-management

I have 550+ fonts installed in my Windows 7, which is annoying, because they all are appear in Adobe Illustrator font's menue. Its really difficult to find appropriate fonts when it needed, also i am scared to add new fonts.
Is there any safe way to delete redundant fonts and group new fonts (may be as folders)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution might be to check out an external font manager, such as [NexusFont](http://www.xiles.net/nexusfont/), which lets you "enable" fonts as you need them while otherwise keeping them hidden (say you're working on a project that needs a handwritten font - you can enable all the fonts tagged "handwriting", and then they'll appear in your font menus in other programs - then you can disable them once you're done with the project).